# jQuery Ajax failing while server side function throws no errors

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to test out getting the details for a book from the isbndb [API](http://isbndb.com/api/v2/docs/books), but I can't tell where the AJAX is failing.

The ajax sends my data properly, and I'm getting valid JSON, but it still defaults to failed. Right now all I have set up is a button to call the Ajax function with some server side code.

Client side:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddBook.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddBook" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#testBtn").click(function () {
            BookDetails();
        });

        function BookDetails() {
            var isbn = '084930315X';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AddBook.aspx/GetBookJson",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    isbnStr: isbn
                }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf - 8",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Success");
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                    console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
                    console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                    console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
                    console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
                    console.log("error: " + err);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <button id="testBtn">Test</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# Server Side:

```
public partial class AddBook : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetBookJson(String isbnStr) {
        string accessKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["isbnKey"];
        string url = "http://isbndb.com/api/v2/json/" + accessKey + "/book/" + isbnStr;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            //Returning a random string from this point on fails 
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.WriteLine(json);
                Debug.WriteLine(IsValidJson(json));
                response.Close();
                return json;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex) {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the expected data, but the ajax function still fails. Something that I noticed is that if I return any random string before `WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();`it works, but after that any return fails.

This is what the console log looks like after the function:

```
readyState: 0
responseText: undefined
status: 0
text status: error
error:
```

This is what the browser inspector says is being returned from AddBook.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#testBtn").click(function () {
            BookDetails();
        });

        function BookDetails() {
            var isbn = '084930315X';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AddBook.aspx/GetBookJson",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    isbnStr: isbn
                }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Success");
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                    console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
                    console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                    console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
                    console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
                    console.log("error: " + err);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

</script>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./AddBook.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="csndqHGqCjV0yNjPCmX8StYTzGC9tkdlWq6Tf8wZm/tZT5H0BPu9j0fkMOGgYc1JKa7vYUSHL6y8W2yNhlnSQYtpNmQYmNjyc4nK7GscTWo=" />
</div>

    <div>
        <button id="testBtn">Test</button>
    </div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="9EBD5A71" />
</div></form>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"e9fcf5f91ca2450fbdca3f4792d459c5"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:52701/9d4e084ff4ea45fe8553128639949211/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you check the browser developer tools network tab, do you see the proper response? by the way `charset=utf - 8` should be `charset=utf-8` (no spaces)

Comment: readyState and status being 0 looks remarkably like a typical CORS problem, by the way. Is the browser request really "same domain" as your code suggests?

Comment: The response from AddBook.aspx seems to just be returning my aspx page. I definitely can't find the response I'm looking for. As for the second question, this is the first time I've tried something like this, so I'm not sure if the browser request is same domain.

Comment: `returning my aspx page` - what? so it's returning the source code you've shown

Comment: Yes. I added what's being returned in my original post to avoid describing it incorrectly. This is just what AddBook.aspx is returning.

Comment: Did you change dataType: "text" to dataType:"json" in ajax request ?

Comment: Yes I've tried both. I've also checked with JsonLint and a method in my code that it is valid Json.